# ¿Como puedo insertar únicamente las filas que estén rellenas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos de 30.000 registros y me gustaría dividirla en 3 distintas.

Como algunos campos están vacíos quiero que se divida entre los que tienen 1 telefono, dos o tres.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
Insert into [dbo].[BBDDTelefono12y3]
 Select [NOMBRE]
      ,[id]
      ,[telefono 1]
      ,[telefono 2]
      ,[telefono 3]
      ,[telefono 4]
      ,[id_ref]
      ,[Id_contacto]
           From [dbo].BBDD_LineaDeNegocioPrueba
where Telefono 3 is not null
```

BBDDTelefono1
BBDDTelefono1y2
BBDDTelefono12y3

He probado a realizar un insert into, pero me agrega todos los resultados en la misma tabla, y no la divide.

Comment: Deberías de incluir unos datos de ejemplo y el resultado que esperas, ya que del script se deduce que quieres 3 tablas, pero en el comentario dices 3 bases de datos.

Comment: Cual es el tipo de la columna `telefono`? Es numérico? De ser así, es nullable? Si es `INT` y no es nullable, entonces, su valor **NUNCA** será `NULL`, será `0`. Es varchar? Es nullable? Pregunto porque, el `WHERE` parece correcto.

Comment: todas son nvarchar

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres duplicar los datos? Deberías estudiar un poco acerca de normalización de bases de datos. Te ayudará a hacer más eficientes tus diseños.

Comment: Esta pregunta parece un duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/500070/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-dividir-una-tabla-en-varias-por-criterios-de-no-nulos

Comment: No quiero duplicar los datos, quiero hacer una tabla que a medida que vayan entrando datos lo divida en 3 lotes o tablas

Comment: En vez de crear nuevas preguntas (de ahí viene lo de duplicadas), puedes mejorar esta pulsando en editar, y así alguién puodrá ayudarte. Pon exactamente lo que tienes (un ejemplo con unas pocas filas) y el resultado esperado (resultado esperado en las 3 tablas). Por otro lado, eso no encaja con tener la base de datos normalizada y es algo bastante importante y a tener en cuenta.